# Expression for numbers displayed to 1 decimal place in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgsexpression, decimal-points

I am having an attribute table in a layout with one of the columns being % values using the expression:

```
to_string("input data_1_ant_care") + to_string('%')
```

The challenge is the numeric variable `"input data_1_ant_care"` may have some values to 1 decimal place and others not. I would like all of them to be displayed to 1 decimal place.

The current output is shown below:

[image]

My desired output is to have 100.0% for county number 1, 98.0% for the 6th etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`format_number()`](https://docs.qgis.orglatest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format-number):

```
 format_number("input data_1_ant_care", 1) + to_string('%')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help